# Ubuntu Unity Question

Tags: 14.04, unity, fullscreen

I'm a long time user of Ubuntu, but since Unity is now the default display manager for Ubuntu, I've moved to KUbuntu, as I cannot stand Unity. However, I'm setting up a system for a friend who likes Unity and wants his system to use it. He also needs to have Virtualbox set up with a Windows 7 VM to allow him to run several Windows programs that will not run in Wine/Crossover. The system is finished and is being used, however, the user runs his Virtualbox Win7 VM in fullscreen, and finds that the Unity top bar (whatEVER its called) prevents his closing/minimizing a fullscreen Windows app by blocking the "big red X" in the fullscreen Windows app. Since I try to stay away from Unity, as I'd like to keep what little hair I have, I'm totally in the dark about any tricks that might solve this problem. Any ideas??

Comment: Fullscreen in Wine/VM programs is a known issue with Unity. I'd recommend Pantheon because it has 1. A dock 2. Window controls on the left

Comment: What is pantheon?

Comment: Pantheon is a DE created by the elementary OS project, based on GTK+ 3 and the goal of being very simple to use.

Comment: Thanks.. Will check it out.. Since besides this issue with fullscreen VB vm's, I'm running into another issue with Unity that I may post another question about, since user is adamant about using Unity on the system in question...

Answer (score 0):

This is a virtualbox issue, more than Unity, but my understanding from reading this:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=43379

Your friend can press the host key, then ALT+SPACE and minimize from full screen.  I have not tried this, so only going by the forum thread.

Comment: This did not work, all I got from pressing host inside the VM then alt-space was an Ubuntu right-click menu, its like the host key was ignored.. I think I'm just gonna take the easy way out and talk user into allowing me to put a more rational DM on his system (XFCE/LXDE/KDE). I've used all of them on Ubuntu and never had any problems like this..  Thanks for the reply..

Comment: Sorry and good luck.

Comment: @lvdave They are DEs (for desktop environments), not DMs (for display managers, which handle graphical login/logout etc.)